# Virtualize a link in jQuery code inside an external javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, virtual-directory

I  am using the following function to virtualize path and reference to my application resources

```
<%= Html.Image( Url.Content( "~/_assets/images/login.png" ), "Login" )%>
```

and this works very fine in resolving the virtual directory where the application has been deployed, for example

```
http://someserver/xyz/_assets/images/login.png
```

how can I achieve the same result when pointing to resources inside a CSS

```
body { background: #F4F4F4 url('/_assets/images/backgr_grad.png') repeat-x 0 0; }
```

and from a javascript function inside an external js file?

```
function loadCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: '/Customers/AllCustomers',
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you not use relative paths inside the CSS and JS files?

Comment: @sheikhomar: do you mean paths relative to the position of the masterpage where both the css and the js are included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CSS you could always use relative paths (in CSS it is relative to the CSS file location):

```
body { 
    background: #F4F4F4 url('../images/backgr_grad.png') repeat-x 0 0; 
}
```

From JS there are different techniques but one consist of defining a global js variable in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customersUrl = '<%: Url.Action("AllCustomers") %>';
</script>
```

and then use this variable in the external javascript file:

```
function loadCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: customersUrl,
        data: { },
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Another technique involves progressive enhancement:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Load customers", "AllCustomers", 
    null, new { id = "customersLink" }) %>
```

And in js progressively enhance this link:

```
$(function() {
    $('#customersLink').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            dataType: "html",
            url: this.href,
            success: function(response) {
            }
        });

        // make sure to cancel the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative path. The path is relative *to the CSS file,* not the page.